# Compare nested objects and list out differences in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, lodash

I want the difference in such a way that the I don't return the entire nested object if any of the values is different.
I have seen solutions online and they all return the entire nested objects and it doesn't work if only 1 key-value pair is changed. i don't want to show the difference as a complete nested object. it should be easier for any user to read.

for eg:

```
const A = {
  position: 2,
  attributes: [{
    code: 123,
    name: "xyz",
    params: {
      label: "hehe",
      units: "currency"
    }
  }],
  code: 1
}

const B = {
  position: 3,
  attributes: [{
    code: 123,
    name: "xyzr",
    params: {
      label: "heh",
      units: "currency"
    }
  }],
  code: 1
}
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
difference: {
   position: {
     current: 2,
     previous: 3
   },
   attributes: {
     current : [{ name: "xyz", params: { label: "hehe" } }],
     previous: [{ name: "xyzr", params: {label: "heh"}}]
   }
}
```

The code that I tried:

```
const compareEditedChanges = (A: any, B: any) => {
    const allKeys = _.union(_.keys(A), _.keys(B));
    try {
      setDifference(
        _.reduce(
          allKeys,
          (result: any, key) => {
            if (!_.isEqual(A?.[key], B?.[key])) {
              result[key] = {
                current: A[key],
                previous: B[key]
              };
            }
            return result;
          },
          {}
        )
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    return difference;
  };
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Comment: `attributes` is an array in the input but an object in the output. How does it look if there are multiple items in the input array?

Comment: @adiga it can be a array of objects in the output as well.

Comment: Please update the expected output

Answer (score 0):

After giving it a lot of thought to the code, I came with my own solution for a deeply nested objects comparison and listing out the differences in an object with keys as current and previous.

I didn't use any inbuilt libraries and wrote the code with simple *for loop*, *recursion* and *map*

```
const compareEditedChanges = (
  previousState,
  currentState
) => {
  const result = [];
    for (const key in currentState) {
      // if value is string or number or boolean
      if (
        typeof currentState[key] === 'string' ||
        typeof currentState[key] === 'number' ||
        typeof currentState[key] === 'boolean'
      ) {
        if (String(currentState[key]) !== String(previousState[key])) {
          result.push({
            [key]: {
              current: currentState[key],
              previous: previousState[key]
            }
            
          });
        }
      }

      // if an array
      if (
        Array.isArray(currentState[key]) ||
        Array.isArray(previousState[key])
      ) {
      console.log(currentState[key])
        if (currentState[key].length > 0 || previousState[key].length > 0) {
        
          currentState[key].map((value, index) => {
            // check for array of string or number or boolean
            if (
              typeof value === 'string' ||
              typeof value === 'number' ||
              typeof value === 'boolean'
            ) {
           
              if (
                JSON.stringify(currentState[key]) !==
                JSON.stringify(previousState[key])
              ) {
              
                result.push({
                  [key]: {
                    current: currentState[key],
                    previous: previousState[key]
                  }
                });
                
              }
            }
            // check for array of objects
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
            
              const ans = compare(
                value,
                previousState[key][index]
              );
              result.push(ans);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }
  return result;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You first need a object:

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({
    number: 0,
    text: "foo"
      });
```

You need to check when the object changed with useEffect, but you also need to see the previos object, for that we will be using a helper function.

```
const prevObject = usePrevious(object);
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (prevObject) {
      if (object.number != prevObject.number) {
        setResult("number changed");
      }
      if (object.text != prevObject.text) {
        setResult("text changed");
      }
    }
  }, [object]);

  //Helper function to get previos
  function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    }, [value]);
    return ref.current;
  }
```

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-cherry-j8md83?file=/src/App.js)